# iOS RestKit artificial identification attributes

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

linked [RestKit issue #1604](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1604)

If my API gives me no `id` attribute, but i still want to cache the objects via Core Data, what should i use to identify my object.
For example i have

```
response =  {
  translation =     {
          text = "longlongtext";
          dictionary = "general";
          lang = "en";
      };
  otherdata =     {
          author = "May";
          date = "434134";
      };
}
```

So i would be glad to use hashed (md5) translation text as an id string.
Notice that my future requests which happen without network connection should be able to identify this cached entity and give it as a result.

I cant declare mapping to fill `responseID` property from `[translation.text md5hash]` to use as `responseMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ responseID ];` because mappings doesnt have such feature.

Comment: So your concern really is matching existing data for offline requests?

Comment: @Wain yep thats what i really care about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As proposed by @segiddins in the github issue discussion:

> ... in your managed object subclass, hook into one of the core data callbacks to generate a compound key that is saved as part of the model and just use that key as your identification attribute.

The approach may look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *identifier;


- (void)willSave
{
    [super willSave];

    NSString *computedIdentifier = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.text, self.langCode] md5hash];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:computedIdentifier forKey:@"identifier"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to do a hash of the `JSON` fields like you, but as you know it's not possible. I ended up doing the following to achieve (I believe) the same end result, which is for `JSON` objects returned without a unique ID, a unique identification attribute is generated by RestKit:

```
    entityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"text",@"dictionary",@"lang",@"author",@"date" ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep this kind of functionality outside of RestKit if you have no identifiers being provided by the server.

I would generate a custom identifier for each request you make (a GUID), I'd save that identifier into each of the result objects in the RestKit success completion block. I'd also save the request details and the identifier into user defaults.

Now, when the user makes a request and they are offline you can analyse user defaults to determine if it's a repeat request and find the identifier with which to query the results from the data store.

Comment: Thanks for response. It makes much sense. But i want to clarify:
I looked through resources:

Comment: I looked through resources:
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping
http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html

and what i learned was that if i use Core Data baked mappings i got offline support out of the box. So if my user turned **airplane mode** and initiated

`[self.objectManager getObjectsAtPath:TRANSLATE_PATH
                              parameters:queryParams
                                 success:<...>    
                                 failure:<...>          
];`

Comment: He still get results somehow.

Comment: But i can assume that it is unreal, because there is no way to assume what entity to fetch from Core Data knowing only the request path.

Comment: So i will try to implement what you suggested.

Comment: One more thing, what if i use `translation.text` as identificationAttribute for CoreData entity named `Response`. Will i get offline mode fetching out of the box then?

Comment: Ok, I guess RestKit is registering the managed object ids against the request internally if that works. I wasn't aware of that feature...

Comment: In the end, such feature (offline requests) does not exist inside RestKit. The way you can achieve it is complicated, but possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify about offline requests after discussion.
In the end, such feature (offline requests) does not exist inside RestKit. The way you can achieve it is complicated, but possible. Steps are:

- you use CoreData with RestKit (RKEntityMapping, managed objects etc)
- Your provide good identification attributes for entities. It can be URL of request from `@metadata`.
- on both `success` and `failure` callbacks from `getObjectsAtPath` you **query** CoreData with fetch request and return the result **just the same way** as if it was loaded directly and taken from `mappingResult.firstObject` and mark it as cached if it is old result loaded **on failure**.